# Como controlar o evento para sair da pagina?

Tags: javascript

Coloquei um evento usando JavaScript em uma tag  `<a>` que  esta estilizado como um botão, o evento serve apenas para mostrar uma mensagem que o usuário irá sair da pagina. Porém a mensagem parece para todas as tags `<a>`, e quero que ele pergunte apenas quando o usuário clicar em **voltar**.

```
    <div>
        <div class="groupb">
            <a href="../cadastrarPaciente.php" class="botoes">Cadastrar</a>
        </div>

        <div class="groupb">
            <a href="../consultarPaciente.html" class="botoes">Consultar</a>
        </div>

        <div class="groupb">
            <a href="../compararPaciente.html" class="botoes">Comparar</a>
        </div>

        <div>
            <form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="fileUpload">
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="groupb">
            <a href="../index.html" onclick="confirmaSaida()" class="botoes">voltar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: [Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/253446/edit) sua pergunta e coloque o código *JavaScript* !!

Comment: Se pergunta para todos os "a" então você deve estar usando bind de alguma função nas tags "a". Pelo código exposto acima até o momento a única tag "a" que chama uma função é o link voltar utilizando o onclick.

Answer (score 2):

Para realizar essa função você precisa implementar a função `confirmaSaida`, chamando `confirm` para verificar se o usuário realmente quer sair, e em caso positivo você redireciona para a página que você quiser, setando `window.location` para o link dessa página.

```js
function confirmaSaida() {
  var option = confirm("Você realmente deseja sair?\nPara sair clique em OK");
  
  if(option) {
    /* Redireciona para a página index */
    window.location = '../index.html'
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="groupb">
        <a href="../cadastrarPaciente.php" class="botoes">Cadastrar</a>
    </div>

    <div class="groupb">
        <a href="../consultarPaciente.html" class="botoes">Consultar</a>
    </div>

    <div class="groupb">
        <a href="../compararPaciente.html" class="botoes">Comparar</a>
    </div>

    <div>
        <form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="fileUpload">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="groupb">
        <a href="#" onclick="confirmaSaida()" class="botoes">voltar</a>
    </div>
</div>
```